# How to subtract 30 days from the current datetime in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How do I subtract 30 days from the current datetime in mysql?

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE exec_datetime BETWEEN DATEDIFF(NOW() - 30 days) AND NOW();
```

Comment: I prefer `SELECT * FROM table
WHERE exec_datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);`

Answer (score 404, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE exec_datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 180):

To anyone who doesn't want to use `DATE_SUB`, use `CURRENT_DATE`:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: More readable but different result than using `NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY`. Since the question mentions "subtract 30 days from the current **datetime**", it may be not what the OP wants.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ then use `current_timestamp` instead of `current_date`

Answer (score 36):

**MySQL subtract days from now:**

```
select now(), now() - interval 1 day
```

Prints:

```
2014-10-08 09:00:56     2014-10-07 09:00:56
```

**Other Interval Temporal Expression Unit arguments:**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals

```
select now() - interval 1 microsecond 
select now() - interval 1 second 
select now() - interval 1 minute 
select now() - interval 1 hour 
select now() - interval 1 day 
select now() - interval 1 week 
select now() - interval 1 month 
select now() - interval 1 year
```

Answer (score 28):

Let's not use `NOW()` as you're losing any query caching or optimization because the query is different every time. See the list of functions you should not use in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-operation.html).

In the code below, let's assume this table is growing with time. New stuff is added and you want to show just the stuff in the last 30 days. This is the most common case.

Note that the date has been added as a string. It is better to add the date in this way, from your calling code, than to use the `NOW()` function as it kills your caching.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE exec_datetime >= DATE_SUB('2012-06-12', INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

You can use `BETWEEN` if you really just want stuff from this very second to 30 days before this very second, but that's not a common use case in my experience, so I hope the simplified query can serve you well.

Comment: So you proposed not no use `NOW()` and still use it in your answer. o_O PS: your query would return **another** result, not what OP probably wants

Comment: @zerkms How would this query produce a different result set than your query?

Comment: @user784637: uhm, `BETWEEN` and `>=` are different operators, you know? My query limits the result set for `30 days ago AND today`, this `everything after 30 days ago`. So `tomorrow` records won't match for mine and your original query, but will match by this answer

Comment: Ok, my bad. Typically such queries are in live tables that are growing with time. That is why I dropped the between. I've clarified my answer above.

Comment: @JosephLust, To solve performance issues, use [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763031/how-to-subtract-30-days-from-the-current-datetime-in-mysql#29439469) instead.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use

```
select CURDATE()-INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT date_format(current_date - INTERVAL 50 DAY,'%d-%b-%Y')
```

You can format by using date format in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the date and not the time use:

```
select*from table where exec_datetime
between subdate(curdate(), 30)and curdate();
```

Since `curdate()` omits the time component, it's [potentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763031/how-to-subtract-30-days-from-the-current-datetime-in-mysql/29439469#comment47469645_29439469) faster than `now()` and more "semantically correct" in cases where you're only interested in the date.

Also, `subdate()`'s 2-arity overload is potentially faster than using `interval`. 
[`interval`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) is meant to be for cases when you need a non-day component.

Comment: So, you are claiming that `subdate(curdate(), 30)` is faaster than `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY`? Do you have proof? And how fast would that be? A few microseconds?

Comment: @ypercube, Wow how did that comment get +5 votes in a day... What did you do? Also, I've clarified in the post that it's "potentially faster".

Comment: I have no idea. I certainly cannot upvote my own comments. About the "potentially" faster claim, I still see no proof, decisive or circumstantial. And even if it is somewhat faster, the condition would be evaluated once. Unless you run the query million of times per minute, the difference will not matter.

Comment: I'm guessing `subdate`'s being potentially faster is probably somehow explained, in your opinion, by its "2-arity overload", but, please forgive me if this is a stupid question, what do those words mean (with respect to a function)? Particularly, what is "2-arity"?

Comment: Also, as far as the wording of the question, `curdate()` may actually be the wrong choice, because the OP seemed to want to "subtract 30 days from the current *datetime*" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @AndriyM, Well since this thread is getting 50k views, I'll leave the answer here for people who are interested in only the time component. And regarding "arity", it's referring to [number of arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity). Yes that's correct, for all things being equal, a 2-arity function is potentially faster than a 3-arity one. That'll hold true until new information is added to the plate.

Comment: @ypercube, Yes I know self-upvotes don't work duh.. I'm referring to whether you've blogged / twittered / etc. And regarding the potentially faster claim, it's [self-standing with the reasoning](http://goo.gl/ax1Eu3) "because it omits the time component". When you have two things to compare whereby the workload of the first is a subset of the second, the first is said to be **potentially faster**. Indeed, this has **nothing to do** with your setup or MySQL version. If you are interested in proof that it runs faster on your particular system, try using `show profiles` and performance schema.

Comment: Ah, all right, I guess I understood it correctly the first time having read "2-arity" as "binarity" (in terms of the number of arguments), but then had some doubts because of the spelling. Also, didn't realise that "arity" existed as a term. (That would probably have helped me to find out sooner what you meant.) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: As for your claim, and explanation, that the binary syntax of SUBDATE() is faster than the INTERVAL syntax, I would agree with you if I knew for certain that the binary syntax is implemented internally as a separate function rather than being there merely as syntactic sugar for `INTERVAL … DAY`.

Comment: @AndriyM, That's besides the point, The point is that it could have been implemented internally as a separate function since the **potential** for that exists. Even if it isn't implemented right now in your particular MySQL setup, a future version could have done that since it's possible to do so. The opposite case whereby the 3-arity function would be faster than the 2-arity one **will not happen** unless there's reason to optimize the 3-arity case without optimizing the 2-arity one................................................................................................................

Comment: .............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................. The only way the 3-arity one will have the upperhand is if you optimize that without optimizing the 2-arity one, because if you actually optimize both of it, the 2-arity one would still have the upperhand.

Comment: No, that is not beside the point. So far you are only guessing that the binary call may have been implemented as a separate function. Sensible guess, but still a guess nevertheless. If it is not a separate function and instead it's just syntactic sugar that resolves internally as a call to the full, ternary, syntax, then all your argumentation, however valid, is irrelevant, because in that case there is no way a binary call can be faster than a corresponding ternary one. In fact, it could be *slower*.

Comment: @AndriyM, I've said this before: whether it's faster or slower is besides the point, because what we're claiming here is **potentially** faster. OK, for purposes of discussion, from now onwards we'll be assuming that `curdate` and 2-arity `subdate` is *slower*, ......................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: ......................................................................... not just *slower* but 99999x slower. Does it change the **fact** that they **can** be implemented in a faster way? Does it change the **fact** that if there are two language-implementation teams competing with each other for a kajillion cash prize, one  trying to optimize the runtime of the string `subdate(x, y)` while the other trying to optimize the runtime of the string `subdate(x, y interval z)`, the first team will definitely have the advantage over the second team? That is what we're saying when we say "potential".

Comment: I wasn't sure if my understanding of what you meant by "potentially faster" (or what it might imply for any reader) was correct, so I asked a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239649/does-is-potentially-faster-imply-is-not-slower) at [english.se] (in case you are interested).

Comment: @AndriyM, Looks like I'm late to the party, but I see you've gotten the answer.

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_debug WHERE TO_DAYS(`when`) < TO_DAYS(NOW())-30 ;
```