# custom sql query for wordpress, using interval

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm trying to COUNT how many videos were posted by "current_user_id" in the last 7 days.

Here is what I wrote but there seem to be a problem with the "interval" part:

```
$total_active_videos_7days = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) 
                              FROM wp_hdflvvideoshare 
                              WHERE member_id = '".$cuid."' 
                              AND publish = 1 
                              AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 day) <= post_date ");
```

Can somebody please lend a hand on this?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: No error message, just the counter show 0...

Comment: use `NOW(),` instead of curdate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763031/how-to-subtract-30-days-from-the-current-datetime-in-mysql