# Get the number of days of difference between two dates in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to get the inactive users for the last 30 days. by that i did this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (30 - lastlogin) > 30
```

However I'm not getting any value, i wanted to see who are the users that did not loggin for the last 30 days. The date of the last login is like that in the database:

```
DD/MM/YYYY
```

Comment: So, the last login date is stored in not `datetime` format?

Comment: What data type of lastlogin - DATETIME, database is MySQL?

Comment: You have specified both `sql-server` and `mysql` tags. Choose the one which is correct.

Comment: There's just too much wrong here. Sit down with a large coffee and a decent book or tutorial and then get back to us

Comment: I've removed `sql-server` because if you are using `mysqli` you aren't using `sqlserver`. If you are using sql-server please add back but sqlserver is separate from mysql; it isn't just a server using sql.

Comment: @Strawberry i don't need to follow your concept in programming, each one has his concept and thanks God there are people who helped me :)

Comment: Yes. Give a man a fish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), str_to_date(`lastlogin`, '%d/%m/%Y')) > 30
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

try use between constraction, for MySql must work follows:

```
select *
from users
where lastlogin between date_sub(now(), interval 30 day) and now();
```

See also: [how to subtrack 30 days from the current datetime in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763031/how-to-subtract-30-days-from-the-current-datetime-in-mysql)