# {date} function help. Fetch record from mysql of specific dates

Tags: php, mysql

I need a help. This code help us when we put specific dates in box.

But if we want records of last 10days then what should we need to do.
Automatic records of last 10 days

```
$sql = "select * from pub_website where  user='$user' &&  STR_TO_DATE(pdate,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$fromdate' && website='$site'";
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but I would opine that you should try writing a single query to get the result set you want, rather than iterating over one query to issue more queries.

Comment: But what query. i need exact date code.

Comment: This this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763031/how-to-subtract-30-days-from-the-current-datetime-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

To `select` all records within a certain date range:

```
SELECT * FROM pub_website WHERE pdate BETWEEN "2015-12-01 00:00:00" AND NOW()
```

To do this dynamically, so to speak, for the last 10 days:

```
SELECT * FROM pub_website WHERE pdate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND NOW();
```