# PHP Mysqli Equal operator not working

Tags: mysql

I'm using Prepared Statement but just for this question, please refer to the sample below:

`'SELECT agentname,agentjoindate FROM agentdatabase WHERE joindate = (NOW() - INTERVAL 11 DAY)'`

Select the name and join date if joindate is exactly 11 days ago. I can't seem to get any results for the above query when there should be at least 1. If I use the greater than or less than it works but not when using equals to. joindate is a date type column in Mysql database. Can't a date type field be equal to `(NOW() - INTERVAL 11 DAY)` because it seems greater than or less than are the only operators that works?

Comment: you use different column names in the select and in the where clause.

Comment: apart from that try `DATE(joindate) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 11 DAY)` otherwise the dates have to be identical up to the second.

Comment: Yes I needed to select the agentname and agentjoindate but the selection will need to be based on a 3rd column `joindate` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"NOW() - INTERVAL 11 DAY" will return a date in the datetime format: 
2016-06-20 16:22:26

If "joindate" is not in that format and instead in a date format it will not match anything. You should then use:
"CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 DAY"

Cheers

Comment: Jeroen explained it well but this works and is simpler. Most of the other answers also worked, didn't bother with the BETWEEN answers though as that is not my goal

Comment: There are always multiple correct answers to a problem. This seemed like the fastest fix ;)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the values, I would assume that your date follows the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

However, `NOW() - INTERVAL 11 DAY` will have the format `yyyy-mm-dd H:m:s`; it will have the time as well.

So even if your date would also have a time, you still would not want to match on only the exact date **and** time.

You can easily solve that by getting the date from that last value:

```
... WHERE joindate = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 11 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, this explanation helped me understood the problem but I will use CURDATE since it seems simpler and I won't need to convert to DATE() anymore

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function to properly subtract dates:

```
SELECT agentname,agentjoindate FROM agentdatabase WHERE joindate = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 11 DAY)
```

I changed `NOW()` to `CURDATE()` because the first returns a DATETIME and the second returns just the date. If `joindate` is a date time, then cast it as a date by using `DATE(joindate`), because otherwise it's going to try to match the exact time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Question is already asked before you can check the below link.

[How to subtract 30 days from the current datetime in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763031/how-to-subtract-30-days-from-the-current-datetime-in-mysql)

and answer is

SELECT agentname,agentjoindate FROM agentdatabase WHERE joindate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW();